# Error message in using Label function

Tags: r

I am new to R and I was using an old function that one of my friends wrote to basically create an HTML table output comparing two groups.

```
mySummary.allvar(data[,c("AGE", "HT", "WT")],group=data$sex,
             pooledGroup=T,contSummary="med.IQR.range",
             caption=paste("Baseline characteristics"),
             filename="Analysis/baseline.html",pval.comparison=T)
```

I have been getting this error message and was wondering how to fix this.

> Error in UseMethod("label<-") : no applicable method for 'label<-'
>   applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: There is no way to help you without a reproducible example. You should share the function

Comment: Could you share the function and information about variable T?